# Factor group of factor group and the 1st isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a question regarding the first isomorphism theorem:

Let $H,K$ be normal subgroups of $G_1$ and $G_2$. Can we then say:

> $(G_1 \times G_2 )/(H\times {e_2})/(e_1\times K)\cong (G_1 \times G_2)/(H\times K)$

I have tried looking at this with the homomorphism theorem, but my brain cant compute so many fractions.

Comment: The l.h.s. is meaningless: neither $e_\times K$ is  neither a subgroup of $H\times e_2$ nor a subgroup of  $G_1\times G_2/H\times e_2$.

Comment: Yes, my thoughts exactly. Aight, I'm relieved now! Thank you Bernard for constantly answering my questions! :) +1

Comment: How your question's header relates to the body of your question??

Comment: @DonAntonio The question is about determining the factor group of a factor group, exactly as the title says. (The OP expects 1st iso thm being relevant in the proof.)

Answer (score 1):

Common abuse of notation: call the trivial subgroup of any group $1$. (This is in the context of abstract groups which are by default interpreted multiplicatively. In the event of, say, additive abelian groups we would use the notation $0$ instead.)

As Bernard points out in the comments, $1\times K$ is a subgroup of $G_1\times G_2$, not of the factor group $(G_1\times G_2)/(H\times 1)$, however the factor group has a subgroup corresponding to it.

The image of $1\times K$ under the projection map $G_1\times G_2\to (G_1\times G_2)/(H\times1)$ will be the normal subroup $(H\times K)/(H\times 1)$ of the factor group. When we quotient the factor group by it:

$$ \frac{(G_1\times G_2)/(H\times 1)}{(H\times K)/(H\times 1)}\cong \frac{G_1\times G_2}{H\times K}\cong \frac{G_1}{H}\times\frac{G_2}{K}. $$

The first is a special case of this: if $N\triangleleft M\triangleleft G$ are normal subroups, then we have

$$ \frac{G/N}{M/N}\cong \frac{G}{M} $$

with the isomorphism given by $gN(M/N)\leftrightarrow gN$. This applies in your context with the substitutions $G=G_1\times G_2$, $M=H\times K$ and $N=H\times 1$.